# "Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token"

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I'm running into a syntax/parsing error, but I can't seem to locate it.

> DataReader.h:11: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token

Here is DataReader.h:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H
#include "Data.h"
#endif

vector<Data*> DataReader();   // This is line 11, where the error is..
```

And this is the .cpp file:

```
#include "DataReader.h"

using namespace std;

vector<Data*> DataReader()
{
 .....
}
```

I skipped the content of DataReader() because I think it's irrelevant, but I can post it if needed.

Thanks for any input/suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your header file, you need to explicitly use `std::vector` rather than just `vector`.

Also, I'm guessing that "Data.h" contains statements of the form:

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H
...
#endif
```

That's fine, but you should not use these include guards across `#include "Data.h"` as well, only within the file itself.

Comment: i.e. have thse #ifndef ... #define .... at the top of Data.h itself, and #endif at this end of this file.  (So all possible files referencing this header do not need to write these few lines).  This is just a style hint, no relation to the compilation error, however.

Comment: It's critical important that you don't have the `#define` line before the `#include` if the included file has `#ifndef` guards base on the same macro as the outer `#ifndef` guards otherwise the contents of the header file will never be included.

Answer (score 4):

In your header file you need to use `std::vector` and not plain `vector` in the declaration of the function `DataReader`.

The standard include `<vector>` causes the `vector` class template to be defined in the `std` namespace and the declaration in your header file happens before any `using namespace std;` or `using std::vector;`.

Answer (score 4):

I think in your header you probably need to write `std::vector<Data*> DataReader();` as the `using namespace std;` is not in scope.

Answer (score 1):

Use std:vector and not vector before Datareader.